# jQuery multiple actions at once

Tags: javascript, php, toggle, href

I'm trying to make some sense with jQuery, but since I never worked with javascript I'm having a bit of trouble.

Basically what am I trying to do.

I have this bit of code:

```
<div>    
  <a href="#"> Text 1 </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <span class="text show" style="display: none">sometext</span>
  <img src="someimage.png">
</div>
```

and I would like to change it to the following:

```
<div>    
  <a href="#"> Text 1 CHANGED</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <span class="text show">sometext</span>
  <img src="someimage.png" style="display: none>
</div>
```

after clicking on link with "text 1".

List of changes:
Change link text
switch image for text and the other way

Every time I click the link it is supposed to switch to the other variation, back and forward.

I have already tried some sollutions I found, mainly javascripts, but since I never worked with them I wasn't able to make it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/j999y/2362/

Comment: Do you mean `jQuery` or is there really something called jquarry

Comment: I think he's just a pirate

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing what you want to do, but the most direct is probably something like this:

```js
$('.text').click(function() {
  $('.text.show').toggle();
  $('.image').toggle();
  $(this).text('Text 1 CHANGED');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>    
  <a href="#" class="text">Text 1</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <span class="text show" style="display: none">sometext</span>
  <img class="image" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/L8b2jHW8ttKu2spXcN6yUjocE_yIBG3E-bBot66cUOj_KsVCm6WcW5A-mxkKM4al6FI=w300-rw">
</div>
```

Comment: This one kinda works, only thing I needed to work it fully is that "Text 1" will change to "Text 1 change" and than back again to "text 1"

Comment: Then you should write that functionality in yourself. I believe I've provided enough of a code sample for you to do that on your own.

Comment: "show" is bootstrap class so it doesn't work, needed other word :) - for other users